# How to tell mod_rewrite to only rewrite when specific urls are being entered?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am having an issue with my .htaccess / .php files
I set up my web project in a way that it's split into 3 levels:

- base level (mywebsite.com)
- pages (mywebsite.com/news)
- subpages/articles (mywebsite.com/news/123)

And all three are working as expected, here's my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&sub=$2 [L]
```

I have to admit, I am not very good with the Regular Expressions for .htaccess/mod_rewrite as it is something I have done very rarely up to this point.

However my issue now is, that people dont get sent to a 404 error page if the page id (see $1) is not valid, like people can technically enter mywebsite.com/asdasdasd/ and it'll bring them (obviously) to the index.php, now my question is, can this be done some way in the .htaccess or should I just use php to check if the id they entered is valid or not? I did see that there's a thing called rewriteMap but I dont want to change the httpd.conf

Can anyone help?

Comment: Usually validating a database `id` is done on php level, not below on the level of the http server. So most likely you want to send a 404 header from your php script that is reponsible to fetch the requested page from the database. Otherwise you'd have to check the database _twice_ which (usually) creates a performance penalty.

Comment: @arkascha so just as I thought, basically get the parameters via the htaccess regex and let php handle the rest and relocate the user to a 404 page if needed, thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can this be done some way in the .htaccess or should I just use php
>   to check if the id they entered is valid or not?

I don't think this is programming problem but logical one.

- Apache **doesn't know** what pages are valid /news /contact /help etc.
- PHP **knows** what pages are valid

So you have only two options

a) Specify every single possible site in `.htaccess` which is terrible practice

**b) Check in PHP is page valid then throw 404 which is only one reasonable solution.**

Comment: Yeah that was, what I thought, I just didn't knew if it could be indeed done via .htaccess, since i have little experience with it ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try this code. Hope this will help you,

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

**index.php**

```
if (isset($_GET['url'])) {
    $url = explode('/',filter_var(rtrim($_GET['url'],'/')), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
    print_r($url);die();
  }
```

Now, in the url you will get all the url segment in the arry format.

```
If your url is: mywebsite.com/news/123 then output will be:

Array ( [0] => news [1] => 123 )
```

you can access and add your own logic or condition as per your need. hope this will help you.

Greetings!

Comment: Right so it simplifies the code for the .htaccess and in turn allows a more "free" way of handling the parameters, that is already nice to have, though  it still remains that I want people to be sent to a 404 page. Can it only be done via php? (not that I dont like that approach, just being very unfamiliar with mod_rewrite's scope, I felt like there could be a possibility to solve it using only regular expressions)

Comment: @Cerbion There is no specific way to check url with apache configuration.